# Beautiful Soup and the findAll() process

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape data from a site using the following code. The site required the decode method and I followed a @royatirek solution. My problem is that container_a ends up containing nothing. I use a similar method on few other sites and it works. But on this and a couple of other sites my container_a variable remains an empty list. Cheers

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'http://www.news.com.au/sport/afl-round-3-teams-full-lineups-and- 
the-best-supercoach-advice/news-story/dfbe9e0e68d445e07c9522a138a2b824'
req = Request(my_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
page_soup = soup(web_byte, "html.parser")
container_a = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"fyre-comment-wrapper"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content you want to parse is being dynamically loaded by JavaScript and therefore `requests` won't do the job for you. You could use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [`ChromeDriver`](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) or any other driver for that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.news.com.au/sport/afl-round-3-teams-full-lineups-and-the-best-supercoach-advice/news-story/dfbe9e0e68d445e07c9522a138a2b824")
```

You can then proceed with the use of bs4 as you wish by accessing the page source using `.page_source`:

```
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
container_a = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"fyre-comment-wrapper"})
```

Comment: Thankyou, this works and it also overcomes the "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" issue that I was having.

Comment: @Chudlee I'm glad to help! Please remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if it was helpful, it's an overall good for the community.